# Using Jquery to show and hide elements based on an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to create a form which changes depending on the users entry. So far I have been successful in using a radio input to change which content is to be shown, but I am having trouble editing the JS to work with a drop down menu.

#### HTML

```
<div class="show-and-hide-content">
    <select>
        <option></option>
        <option data-type="true">true</option>
        <option data-type="false">false</option>
    </select>
    <div class="hidden content content-true">You have selected true.</div>
    <div class="hidden content content-false">You have selected false.</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

#### Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('.show-and-hide-content').each(function (i) {
        var $row = $(this);
        var $selects = $row.find('select');
        $selects.on('change', function () {
            var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
            $row
                .find('.content').hide()
                .filter('.content-' + type)
                    .show();
        });
    });
});
```

[Working radio button JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm5xW/)

[Non working drop down JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r6zb/)

I know that the JQuery is finding the right elements and is changing the display of them, but it never changes the display to make them visible. I think the problem may be that the JS isn't correctly getting the data-type variable from the option's.

I want the JQuery to work as intended and show the correct divs based on the users selection.

How can I amend the code to do this? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You now got:

```
var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
```

Since the function is called on the `<select>`, you select the `data-type` attribute of the `<select>` (which is defined), and not from the `<option>`.

So, you'll need to find the selected `<option>`:

```
var type = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-type');
```

Check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7r6zb/10/).

**[EDIT]**

If you want to simplify your code, you could use this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.show-and-hide-content select').on('change', function() {
        $(this).parent().
            find('.content').hide()
            .filter('.content-' + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-type') ).show();
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7r6zb/15/).

Answer (score 1):

Or change your select `data-type` to `value` and use

```
var type = $(this).val();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rameshcharykotha/7r6zb/13/)

Comment: Thank for pointing that out. Doing this should clean the code up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(function () {
    $('#select').on('change', function () {
        var selctedval  = $(this).val();
        $('.content').hide();
        $('.content-' + selctedval).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will use whatever value you have in the "data-type" attribute and match it to the "content-" class that you have on the message. If there is no matching message then, no message will show.

```
$('.show-and-hide-content select').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').data('type');
    $('.content').addClass('hidden');
    $('.content-' + selected).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OrngTicTac/Y564R/1/)**